# How do I create a simple SOAP server using C# in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, soap

I was trying to follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) but they seem to quickly be getting very specific to Sharepoint, as they go along further.  I just want a general tutorial for creating a non-sharepoint SOAP starter projects, and Google is not my friend, at the moment.

It seems that some of the above steps are applicable.

So far I have:

1. A solution 'WebSite1' created with File -> New Website.
2. A 'ClassLibrary1' project in C#, with System.Web.Services added to References.
3. a key02.snk (strongname key file) file node in the classlibrary1.
4. No code implementing any SOAP server methods yet.
5. No idea how to add code to the above, and then build and run, and have a soap hello-world type method.

I'd like to implement a simple HelloWorld method that takes at least one parameter. The resulting service could be queried for its WSDL with a url like this:

```
    http[s]://localhost/myfirstsoapserver/helloWorldMethod1.asmx?WSDL
```

If my guess above is right, the above Url would be usable by any tool that can import WSDL.

My goal is rapid prototyping and mocking up of various other SOAP interfaces that I need to deal with, and I'm hoping that C#+visualStudio2010+IIS is a reasonably easy way to do that.

Comment: If you did not notice the link you posted is from "SharePoint Foundation 2010 General Reference"

Comment: I did notice, after a while. :-)  Silly me. It turns out that for what I need, the two steps in the accepted answer are perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a new project as a web application:
[image]

Then add a new item of type web service:
[image]

Comment: For my purposes, this fits better than WCF. But it's great to know about both.

Comment: How would I address the wsdl from this service?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using WCF?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: Hey that works great. I had no idea WCF was so easy to get started with. And the WCF test client is there and everything.

Comment: The WCF framework has a lot to recommend it, including the WcfTestClient.